# Analytic continuation of scattering phase shift

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, s-matrix-theory

In scattering theory, the resolvent, $S$-matrix, $T$-matrix, etc. are formally defined for any complex energy, $z$, even if most practical calculations consider just the positive real energy axis, $z=E$. One such practical calculation is in partial wave analysis of finite-range central force scattering problems, where it is often useful to compute the scattering phase shift, $\delta_l(E)$, which relates to the $S$- and $T$-matrices by
$$
S_l(E) = \exp[2i\delta_l(E)] \\
T_l(E) = \exp[i\delta_l(E)] \sin[\delta_l(E)]
$$
I would like to know if phase shift also has a meaningful analytic continuation to complex energies, and if this analytic continuation relates to the $S$- and $T$-matrices in the naive way, i.e,
$$
S_l(z) \overset{?}{=} \exp[2i\delta_l(z)] \\
T_l(z) \overset{?}{=} \exp[i\delta_l(z)] \sin[\delta_l(z)]
$$